# Code a button on a woocommerce product page to download a CSV with product data

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I'm trying to code a function to put a button on a Woocommerce Single Product Page, that when clicked it downloads a CSV with all woocommmerce data on it.

Currently, if I put the code in functions.php, the button clicks and opens a blank tab, but no CSV. Any idea how to fix or what the problem may be?

```
// Add Download CSV button on product page
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_download_csv_button', 25 );
function add_download_csv_button() {
    global $product;
    echo '<a href="' . get_home_url() . '/export-csv/?product_id=' . $product->get_id() . '" class="button">Download CSV</a>';
}

// Generate CSV file on button click
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'generate_csv_file' );
function generate_csv_file() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['product_id'] ) && $_GET['product_id'] != '' ) {
        $product_id = intval( $_GET['product_id'] );
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        // Set CSV headers
        header( 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=product-' . $product_id . '.csv' );

        // Create CSV file
        $output = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
        fputcsv( $output, array( 'Product Name', 'Product SKU', 'Product Description', 'Product Price' ) );
        fputcsv( $output, array( $product->get_name(), $product->get_sku(), $product->get_description(), $product->get_price() ) );
        fclose( $output );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the `template_redirect` hook for this is really not the thing to do here. You should set up a proper endpoint via the Rest API for this, https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work, what if we make a tweak to your `echo` and replace:

`add_action( 'template_redirect', 'generate_csv_file' );`

with

`add_action( 'init', 'generate_csv_file' );`

```
// Add Download CSV button on product page
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_download_csv_button', 25 );
function add_download_csv_button() {
    global $product;
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( add_query_arg( 'product_id', $product->get_id(), home_url( '/export-csv/' ) ) ) . '" class="button">Download CSV</a>';
}

// Generate CSV file on button click
add_action( 'init', 'generate_csv_file' );
function generate_csv_file() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['product_id'] ) && $_GET['product_id'] != '' ) {
        $product_id = intval( $_GET['product_id'] );
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        // Make sure that the product data is valid
        if ( ! $product ) {
            return;
        }

        // Set CSV headers
        header( 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=product-' . $product_id . '.csv' );

        // Create CSV file
        $output = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );
        fputcsv( $output, array( 'Product Name', 'Product SKU', 'Product Description', 'Product Price' ) );
        fputcsv( $output, array( $product->get_name(), $product->get_sku(), $product->get_description(), $product->get_price() ) );
        fclose( $output );
        exit;
    }
}
```